# Saving javascript script output to file on server

Tags: javascript, linux, file, logging, output

So far Gurus here helped me a lot so far and I am back again with my little queries again.

I have a js that is being called from a webserver through a internal site I am taking care of. js has lots of very helpful debugging comments through

> console.log($output)

that are being displayed on the console. I was wondering if there is any way i can redirect these comments to a log file on server.

I know it is hard but not impossible... I thought of doing something like

```
> exec 1>>${LOG_FILE}
```

but then it means it will get outputs from every file will be going to that file.

I only need the output from one file... is it possible?? plus do I need to run it through cron? because I don't have permission to change anything in js itself.

-Thanks

Comment: The server is only supplying the javascript file to the client (the web browser), and it is not until it has reached the web browser that the code is run.  The browser has no access to write data on to the server directly.

Comment: So is it not possible at all? Anyone ? :-(

Comment: You would have to explicitly create a client/server architecture in order to achieve this.  For example, creating a ajax request to send data back to the server to be logged.